# Question about LeetCode 279. Perfect Squares

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

Given a positive integer n, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) which sum to n.

Example 1:

Input: n = 12
Output: 3 
Explanation: 12 = 4 + 4 + 4.

Example 2:

Input: n = 13
Output: 2
Explanation: 13 = 4 + 9.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public int numSquares(int n) {
        int i = 1;
        int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(i * i < (n / 2)) {
            int start = i * i;
            int step = BFS(start,n);
            if(step < ret)
                ret = step;         
            i++;
      }

        return ret;
    }

    public int BFS(int start, int n) {
        int step = 0;
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        queue.offer(start);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
             int node = queue.poll();
             step++;
             if(node == n)
                 break;
             for(int k=1;k*k <= n;k++){
                 if(k*k <= n)
                 queue.offer(k * k + node); 
                 if(node + k*k == n)
                     return step + 1;
             }          
        }
        return step;
    }


}
```

I have problems updating the step value. I can't come up with a solution how to update the step value. Can anyone help?

Comment: IMHO, this question has a dp solution. So why bothering try to find a BFS one?

Comment: It 's under the BFS problems collection so that I used BFS. And I hope I can figure out this specific solution.

Comment: This question has a surprisingly simple solution. Start with [Lagrange four-squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem), and follow the links  for three-squares, and two-squares theorems.

Comment: @user58697 consider posting a solution. Looking at the links I couldn't see an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I will try to update the `step` value, by detect some `marker` between different `levels` in the `BFS` procedure, who can tell us that we are hitting the end of previous level and are going into the next level. I usually employ a `null` element as this `marker`.

See my code with comments,   which has been accepted:

```
public class Solution {
    public int numSquares(int n) {
        Queue<Integer> queue=new LinkedList();
        queue.add(n);
        queue.add(null);//a null element to show the gap between two levels,i.e., the step
        int res=1;
        while(true){
            Integer i=queue.element();

            if(queue.size()!=1&&i==null){// we are hitting the marker
                queue.remove();
                res++;//i.e., step+1
                queue.add(null);//think about why we need add an additional marker here.
            }else{
                Integer sqrt=(int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(i));
                if(sqrt*sqrt==i){
                    break;
                }else{
                    queue.remove();
                    for(int j=sqrt;1<=j;j--){
                        if(0<i-j*j)
                            queue.add(i-j*j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

PS,as stated:

> Most standard library headers are already included automatically for your convenience.

So we don't do `import java.util.*` and the code can compile.